# Why cant I get Data from ClipBoard trough an Remote Desktop session?

Tags: c#, wpf, clipboard

I want to get the Data from the ClipBoard on an RemoteDesktop.

The Data Ive getting is an path of an File I have in ClipBoard

The Code im using looks like this:

```
   IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

                if (!data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
                    return;

                string[] filePath = (string[])
                  data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
```

And for the local Computer its working perfectly.

But when Im using the Programm on an Remote Computer I cant use the ClipBoard there.

Clipoard is activated on Remote so If i want to paste something from my ClipBoard normal on the Remote Computer its working but my Code dosent find an ClipBoard.

Someone an Idea?

Comment: **Where** is your program running?

Comment: the Programm is on Remote Computer running and the File Ive got in the ClipBoard is on my Local Computer

Comment: What about any of the other formats, such as `DataFormats.Serializable`

Comment: dont do the magic sadly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `DataFormats.FileDrop` is the correct format for what you want. [According to MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dataformats.filedrop):

> Use this format to interact with shell file drags during drag-and-drop operations.

You don't want drag-and-drop, you're using the clipboard.

You can call `data.GetFormats()` to get a list of the available formats the object supported by on the clipboard. When I test this I see two formats that may be useful to you: `FileGroupDescriptorW` and `FileContents`. I would suggest looking into those and learning how to parse the data therein.

One place you might look to get started with `FileGroupDescriptorW` is [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/e9fecc6d-70d4-4c11-a16c-ff763e56155a/drop-outlook-attachment-to-wpf-form?forum=wpf). They're doing something lightly different (trying to get drag and drop from Outlook), but they make use of `FileGroupDescriptorW` and have all the needed definitions that are currently missing from pInvoke.net.

Comment: How did I need to define this? Because data.GetFormats() need an parameter and DataFormats.FileContents for example I cant find.

Comment: @NadiaBallshek [IDataObject.GetFormats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.idataobject.getformats) does not require a parameter, so I assume you meant [IDataObject.GetData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.idataobject.getdata). It doesn't seem like `DataFormats` has a field for `FileContents`, but they're just strings, so you can just do `data.GetData("FileContents")`.

Comment: With this :  var filePath = 
                     data.GetData("FileGroupDescriptorW");   I get an MemoryString, with FileContents() I get an error, the problem is how to get on the exact data from that Memory Stream now ?

Comment: `FileContents` will contain the binary data for file(s) being copied. `FileGroupDescriptorW` gives you some info about those files, like the file names. To read the data from `FileGroupDescriptorW` you'll need to do some pInvoke.

Comment: When I try to convert the memory Stream to string I get no usefule data from it:                                   string  settingsString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
 and how to do an pInvoke I have no Idea

Comment: It's not a string, it's the raw binary of whatever file(s) has been copied. What are you actually trying to do with this files in your program? Save them somewhere? Open them somehow?

Comment: Its normally an Excel File and I want to edit the data of the excel File and when the User Copy it in I want to save it in an temp file to edit it and the user save it after that where he want, but at first I need the File path to save it temporaly on the remote Computer where the Program is running to edit the File

Comment: I added a bit of info to the answer that might help you figure out how to get started. pInvoke can get kinda complicated.

Comment: I see this Question getting a bit more expanded, I mark this Answer as accepted answer, but I made an Expanded new version of the Question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74013599/pasting-an-excel-file-to-an-my-programm-which-is-running-on-an-remote-computer-d