# Pasting an Excel File to my program which is running on an remote computer doesn't work

Tags: c#, remote-access, data-objects

I have my `Computer` on which I have an `Excel File`. This File I want to `copy and Paste` to my program which is running on a `Remote Computer.`

After that `Copy` I want to use this file and make `Excel.Interop changes` and after that I want to save a new Excel file which is different from the file I copied to my program.

If I want to copy the file from the `Remote Computer` in the program which is still runing on the `same Remote Computer` it's working with this code:

```cs
IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

if (!data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    return;

string[] filePath = (string[])
data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
```

But when I get to the point on where I want to copy data from my main PC to my remote computer on which the program is running, it doesn't work.

The only way to get some data from the other computer's pasted file, is with this Code:

```cs
MemoryStream fileGroupDescriptorStream = (MemoryStream)dataObject.GetData("FileGroupDescriptorW", true);
```

With `FileGroupDescriptorW` I get the bytes from the file but with it I cannot do much because I can't get access to the excel file I copy paste here.

To encrypt it and get the file to get the filename etc., I found this Code from this question: [Question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/e9fecc6d-70d4-4c11-a16c-ff763e56155a/drop-outlook-attachment-to-wpf-form?forum=wpf)

With that I tried this Code:

```cs
private System.Windows.IDataObject underlyingDataObject;
private System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject comUnderlyingDataObject;
private System.Windows.IDataObject oleUnderlyingDataObject;
private MethodInfo getDataFromHGLOBLALMethod;
public void ObjectData(System.Windows.IDataObject underlyingDataObject)
{
    this.underlyingDataObject = underlyingDataObject;
    this.comUnderlyingDataObject = (System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject)this.underlyingDataObject;

    //FieldInfo innerDataField = this.underlyingDataObject.GetType().GetField("innerData", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    //FieldInfo innerDataField = this.underlyingDataObject.GetType().GetField("innerData", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    FieldInfo innerDataField = this.underlyingDataObject.GetType().GetField("_innerData", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    this.oleUnderlyingDataObject = (System.Windows.IDataObject)innerDataField.GetValue(this.underlyingDataObject);
    this.getDataFromHGLOBLALMethod = this.oleUnderlyingDataObject.GetType().GetMethod("GetDataFromHGLOBLAL", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public sealed class FILEGROUPDESCRIPTORW
{
    public uint cItems;
    public FILEDESCRIPTORW[] fgd;
}

public sealed class SIZEL
{
    public int cx;
    public int cy;
}

public sealed class POINTL
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public sealed class FILEDESCRIPTORW
{
    public uint dwFlags;
    public Guid clsid;
    public SIZEL sizel;
    public POINTL pointl;
    public uint dwFileAttributes;
    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftCreationTime;
    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftLastAccessTime;
    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;
    public uint nFileSizeHigh;
    public uint nFileSizeLow;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
    public string cFileName;
}
```

and the part where I paste the file:

```cs
private void Border_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    View.path = null;
    if (e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.V)
        {
            IDataObject dataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
            IntPtr fileGroupDescriptorWPointer = IntPtr.Zero;
            MemoryStream fileGroupDescriptorStream = (MemoryStream)dataObject.GetData("FileGroupDescriptorW", true);

            byte[] fileGroupDescriptorBytes = new byte[fileGroupDescriptorStream.Length];
            fileGroupDescriptorStream.Read(fileGroupDescriptorBytes, 0, fileGroupDescriptorBytes.Length);
            fileGroupDescriptorStream.Close();

            fileGroupDescriptorWPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(fileGroupDescriptorBytes.Length);
            Marshal.Copy(fileGroupDescriptorBytes, 0, fileGroupDescriptorWPointer, fileGroupDescriptorBytes.Length);

            object fileGroupDescriptorObject = Marshal.PtrToStructure(fileGroupDescriptorWPointer, typeof(FILEGROUPDESCRIPTORW));
            FILEGROUPDESCRIPTORW fileGroupDescriptor = (FILEGROUPDESCRIPTORW)fileGroupDescriptorObject;

            string[] fileNames = new string[fileGroupDescriptor.cItems];
            IntPtr fileDescriptorPointer = (IntPtr)((int)fileGroupDescriptorWPointer + Marshal.SizeOf(fileGroupDescriptor.cItems));

            for (int fileDescriptorIndex = 0; fileDescriptorIndex < fileGroupDescriptor.cItems; fileDescriptorIndex++)
            {
                //marshal the pointer top the file descriptor as a FILEDESCRIPTORW struct and get the file name
                FILEDESCRIPTORW fileDescriptor = (FILEDESCRIPTORW)Marshal.PtrToStructure(fileDescriptorPointer, typeof(FILEDESCRIPTORW));
                fileNames[fileDescriptorIndex] = fileDescriptor.cFileName;

                //move the file descriptor pointer to the next file descriptor
                fileDescriptorPointer = (IntPtr)((int)fileDescriptorPointer + Marshal.SizeOf(fileDescriptor));
            }
            MessageBox.Show(fileNames[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

But now I get the exception : **"An attempt was made to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."**

So, does anyone have an idea how to copy the Excel file from my computer, and then pasting the Excel file to my program which is running on an RemoteDesktop. And from there to edit the File so that it is better to copy the pasted file to a temp folder maybe.

Comment: DCOM would probably be a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem to drag and drop files in .NET 7.
You have to change:

```
IntPtr fileDescriptorPointer = (IntPtr)((int)fileGroupDescriptorWPointer + Marshal.SizeOf(fileGroupDescriptor.cItems));
```

to

```
IntPtr fileDescriptorPointer = (IntPtr)((long)fileGroupDescriptorWPointer + Marshal.SizeOf(fileGroupDescriptor.cItems));
```

and this:

```
fileDescriptorPointer = (IntPtr)((int)fileDescriptorPointer + Marshal.SizeOf(fileDescriptor));
```

to

```
fileDescriptorPointer = (IntPtr)((long)fileDescriptorPointer + Marshal.SizeOf(fileDescriptor));
```

this works for me fine in .NET 7

Comment: You should probably mention in your answer you are changing the Data Type from `int` to `long` just to make it easier to 'see'/understand the change you are suggesting.